# finding size of a sequence using a common interface

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

I want to determine the size of a sequence. For all sequences in STL i can use .size() member function but if the sequence is an array, I will get into trouble. How can i programmatically determine if the sequence passed as the argument is an array type or a STL sequence type.

e.g.

```
template<typename sequence>
size_t find_size(sequence& s)
{
// if s has .size() member function 
// return s.size()
//else if it is an array type 
// return sizeof(s)
//else throw error
}
```

Basically i am looking for a non-member size function just like we have non-member begin() and end() in C++11

PS: by sequence I mean the sequence as defined in STL(all of them have a .size() member function), including arrays as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by overloading your `find_size` function for arrays.

```
// This overload expects an array to be passed by reference.
template<typename T, size_t N> 
size_t find_size(T (&)[N]) { 
  return N; 
}

// This overload takes any other type that supports T::size().
template<typename T> 
size_t find_size(T c) { 
  return c.size(); 
}
```

Note that this won't work for arrays that have degraded into pointers, however. Also, I would always suggest using `std::array` over C-style arrays, unless you're working with a C library.

Comment: actually, i want to have such an interface so that it is independent of any sequence type.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You want to achieve the same result using only one function, not two?

Comment: overloaded functions are also fine.

Answer (score 1):

you could use something as following:

```
template<typename T>
size_t find_size(const T& c)
{ 
    return distance(begin(c), end(c));
}
```

though I don't claim that it is efficient in any way. Getting the size of a sequence is not independent of that sequence (for example, finding the size of a linked-list is fundamentally different from finding the size of a vector), and it will be more efficient as dauphic suggested by providing overloads for each specific type of sequence which does not implement .size

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really explained in details what is (and what isn't) a sequence, but if it's similar in concept and execution to Boost.Range then perhaps [`boost::size`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/concept_implementation/semantics/functions.html) is of interest to you.